# Check <th> value and update in <td> based on condition

Tags: php

I have a result and a json , where $response['json'] contain table header columns and table data comes for the $response['results']. i need to check if the header contain column name as "NN ID" then respective table column data should be in a anchor `<a href="">Data</a>`   tag.

PHP code:

```
$json = $response['JSON'];
$result = $response['RESULT'];

echo '<strong>Search Results</strong>   
 <h4 class="bg-default"><strong>Total Records ('.count($result).')</strong></h4>';

if (count($result) > 0) {

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
            <tr>';
                foreach (array_values($json) as $column) {
                    echo '<th>'.$column.'</th>';
                }
            echo '</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach (array_keys($json) as $field) {
                    echo '<td>'.$row[$field].'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo '</tbody>
    </table>';

}
```

Need to add href for

```
  <td>
     <a onclick="parent.LoadIframe(\'/view.php?nnid='.$row[field].'\')">
        '.$row[field].'
    </a>
  </td>
```

Current View:

[image]

Need View as a link for NN ID Column data

[image]

Comment: This is still rather unclear: define ' header contain column name as "NN ID" '. Give us an example of the data, and the example output.

Comment: Franker , i have added a screen shots how i need.

Comment: I don't see any screenshots

Comment: Can you check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple if statement is all you need:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ( array_keys($json) as $field) {
                if ( $field == 'NN ID' ) {
                    echo '<td><a onclick="parent.LoadIframe(\'/view.php?nnid='.$row[$field].'\')">
    '.$row[$field].'
</a></td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td>'.$row[$field].'</td>';
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
```